# "Arguments to methods are never optional"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am starting into the second lecture of Stanford's iOS programming course on itunes and am confused as to what the above statement means exactly. It is in the slides and lecture itself:
'Arguments to methods (like the atTop: argument) are never optional'.

Here is the example method the lecturer is referring to when he says arguments are never 'optional':

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
```

He goes on to say that if you want 'an addCard: method without addTop: we can define it separately':

As in,

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card;
```

I'm just confused about what he means. I always thought that method arguments were always optional but I think I'm missing something obvious. Does he just mean that in this case you can't leave atTop: just hanging there as it is linked to first method?

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: He's saying you should define two completely separate methods, because optionals aren't supported. One method takes atTop, the other simply doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective C method signatures are a unique beast. In the case of

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
```

the actual function signature is `addCard:atTop:`, meaning `addCard:` will not be recognized because it is not defined (unless you have explicitly defined it elsewhere). That said, you can always pass `nil` in place of any pointer argument, but this would not work in this case because `BOOL` is primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Well in Objective-C methods (or selectors) are define by the whole name, in your case:

```
-(void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;

is this name: addCard:atTop:

And 

-(void)addCard:(Card *)card;

is: addCard:
```

There are deferents methods, although the implementation of this second method could be:

```
 -(void)addCard:(Card *)card
 {
  [self addCard:card atTop:NO];
 }
```

But there are difference methods (selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, he's saying if you have a method like:

```
- (void)playSport:(Sport*)s onField:(Field*) atTime:(NSDate)when;
```

You can't just call:

```
[object playSport: sport];
```

You didn't supply all parameters, so you didn't send the defined method a message, you sent it to something that is not defined.

But if you define a method that does accept just that 1 parameter then it'll of course work.